# WKT to SDO_Geometry

Tags: java, oracle, geometry

I need to transform data from **Well Known-Text to Oracle SDO_Geometry**. I found the method SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY in Oracle that is perfect for my porpuses but it takes a long time and I need to transform a lot of geometries. Also, I know about the SDOAPI in Java but I didn't found any useful method there and I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Are there any Java API or SQL method to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: You have something that works so you should be able to post a test case.  When you post that test case, tell us how long it takes and how long you need it to take.  If we're looking to makes something 100x faster, that's a very different thing than making something 2x faster and probably involves a very different approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution in the package oracle.spatial.util in SDOUTL.jar and SDOAPI.jar included in Oracle to convert from WKT to SDO_Geometry and  vice-versa:

```
String geom = "MULTIPOLYGON (..."
byte[] bgeom = geom.getBytes();
WKT wkt = new WKT ();
JGeometry jgeom = wkt.toJGeometry(bgeom);
bgeom = wkt.fromJGeometry(jgeom);
System.out.println(new String(bgeom, "UTF-8"));
```